# Parse exception string

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way to parse an Exception's ToString() output back into an Exception object?  Imagine I have this string:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.  
    at Sandbox.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Development\Personal\Sandbox\Program.cs:line 12
```

I'd like to pass that value to a method and have it return an Exception object where I can then pull out the name, message, stack trace etc.  Is this possible in .NET, or is there another library/project that can do this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happened to the original exception?

Comment: Some developers though it would be a good idea to stick multiple Exceptions' ToString() outputs in a single field in a database, delimeted by semicolons.  Now I get to clean up--without being able to change how the database is populated, of course.  :)

Comment: I'd love to give you +200 moral points for that.  Wowsers.

Comment: Interesting question, but I don't think there's anything out there that does what you want. If you have no choice but to tackle it, you may be looking at a bunch of regexes or a sequential parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible just from the string (or at least from the minimal string you've shown).

Best is to have a global error handler that can catch uncaught exceptions.

If you're in ASP.Net, `Server.GetLastError()` can help you retrieve the exception object.

Comment: The Op's strings are in a database. Too late for GetLastError().

Comment: Well then, string parsing it is. Down and dirty!